# Android - Bitmaps rotation

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I have the following problem, I want to rotate two bitmaps. As you can see in the attached picture. "X" is pivot point. Bitmap 2 must rotate about the same angle as bitmap 1. I can't rotate whole canvas, only this two bitmaps.
After rotation bitmaps must be in the same position, relative to each other.

I doesn't have any problem with first bitmap rotation.

```
        matrix1.reset();
        matrix1.postTranslate(width2*0.13f, height2*0.205f);
        matrix1.preRotate(-5, a*0.5f,b*0.973913f);
```

I do not know how to set parameters for second Bitmap matrix. 
How to set pivot point in matrix2 outside Bitmap 2 area ? 
Or is there any other solution ?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Problem]

Comment: use same layout for that and set rotation to for layout

Comment: I can not do that. In this application, all bitmaps must be on the same layout.

Comment: "I can't rotate whole canvas" - Why not? `save()` the `Canvas`, `rotate()` it, draw your `Bitmap`s, then `restore()`.

Comment: I know how to rotate canvas. But this is not the solution. On this canvas I have other bitmaps, which I don't want to move or rotate

Comment: That's why you `save()` and `restore()` around the `rotate()` and those two `drawBitmap()` calls. Only those two `Bitmap`s will be rotated.

Comment: Thanks @Mike M., your solution works great. I thought canvas.save () and restore () works only on whole canvas.